# how can i fix crond[296824]: No configuration file found at /root/.esmtprc or /etc/esmtprc?

Tags: linux, cron, centos

I use aws crontab to run my task.

it ran smoothly for some days, but today, i found crontab failed, when i open /var/log/cron
it failed to print new message, and i found

```
crond[296824]: No configuration file found at /root/.esmtprc or
/etc/esmtprc
```

in /var/log/messages, and all mail log is empty.
My Os is Centos8, can anyone offer some suggestions? Thanks a lot

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/727772/65319

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Today I had the same problem. Cron send mail notifications about errors, so it take destination info from *"~/.esmtprc"*. If you haven't configured propertly this file, you could get that error in cron log:

```
crond[296824]: No configuration file found at /root/.esmtprc or /etc/esmtprc
```

All mails whit errors that cron couldn't sent are locate in *"~/.esmtp_queue/"*.